# Microblink: Failed to load resource uae_name_dictionary in latest Version 4.9.1

Tags: ios, swift, microblink, blinkid

I am using the Microblink framework for scanning the Emirates ID. I have successfully integrated the Microblink framework with version 4.4.0, but now I want to upgrade it to the latest version 4.9.1.

I have replaced the framework and bundle file with the latest one, the application starts crashing on the Scan emirates Id screen and shows the following log on console.

"Failed to load resource uae_name_dictionary. The program will now crash!"

**Environment:**

1. Xcode version:10.2
2. BlinkID SDK version: 4.9.1
3. What are you trying to scan? Emirates ID

Does anyone know how to deal with this kind of error? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the framework and bundle files completely and then adding the new ones (framework and bundle version 4.9.1) to your project.

In version 4.8.0 we renamed the framework from MicroBlink to Microblink to be more in line with our brand. Since your OS is case insensitive it doesn't detect the change in name, while the linker for example does.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This issue occurred due to the missing the path, as the uae_named_dictionary.zzip file not able to load at runtime. By adding the Microblink framework in the embedded path and adding Microblink bundle into the Copy bundle again, resolved this issue.